# Where is the 'New Team Build Type' option in the build menu?

Tags: tfs, build-process, build

I'm following instructions on how to create a new build type in TFS, and it says to:

1. In team explorer, select the project you want to create a new build type
2. on the build menu, select **new team build type**

My build menu doesn't have that option, it has:

- Queue new build
- New build definition
- Manage build agents, and
- Manage build qualities.

Is this old docs or is my setup wrong?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Sounds like you are reading docs that are for Visual Studio 2005 talking to TFS 2005.  The build system was completely re-written for Visual Studio 2008 and is much improved.

For a basic walkthough of creating a new build in 2008 see the following on MSDN:

> http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms181286.aspx

Good luck,

Martin.